# Regex exclude criteria

Tags: regex, regex-negation

After some tries I have created the follow regex:

```
/([^\w][[:alnum:]]*\.)/g
```

That matches results as this image:

[image]

In the secod case, pointed by red arrow I got `"=U."` as match, but I only want `"U."` (rather if without spaces before) and `"A2."` - how can I exclude **"="** (equal) char from match criteria?

See the live example: http://regex101.com/r/cI9fL1

Comment: Not a word character `\W` matches an awfull lot of stuff. How do you distinquish relavent data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use a *lookbehind*:

```
/(?<=\W)([[:alnum:]]*\.)/
```